# Bootstrap Selectpicker will not reset using built-in functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have an array of Bootstrap Selectpickers for filtering results from a database. I need a way of resetting all the selectpickers to 'Nothing Selected', this is my code:

## HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>By Group</label>
        <select id="groups" name="group" class="form-control selectpicker" multiple></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        etc...
    </div>
</div>
```

## JS

```
ajax_fetch('build_group_options', {groupno:groupno}).done(function(html) {
    //var html is a list of options in html format
    $('#groups').html(html).find('option[value=""]').remove();
    //refresh the selectpicker to make sure options are registered in the picker
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
});
```

**Try to reset all the pickers:**

```
$('#reset_filters').click(function() {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('deselectAll');
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    $(this).closest('form').find('.selectpicker').each(function() {
        $(this).selectpicker('render');
    });
});
```

As you can see I have tried all the functions to reset but to no avail so am obviously doing some wrong further up the logic.

Comment: Tried your 'reset' code snippet today, and that deselected my select boxes. So this might have been fixed since you had this problem. Just a comment for someone else later.

Comment: You are the real MVP. If you check silviomoreto's github (https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select) you will see he has drastically changed the code over the past couple of years. v1.6.3 -> v1.12.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I looked in the selectpicker.js file, the `deselectAll` and `selectAll` functions both filter their respective options by a few arguments (see line 884):

```
deselectAll: function () {
  this.findLis();
  this.$lis.not('.divider').not('.disabled').filter('.selected').filter(':visible').find('a').click();
}
```

**A little breakdown:**

```
.not('.divider') //prevents the divider receiving a click event! 
.not('.disabled') //ignore any disabled elements
.filter('.selected') / .not('.selected') //depending if its selectAll() or deselectAll()
.filter(':visible') //prevent any non-visible element receiving a click event!?
```

My problem was the `.filter(':visible')`, the list was not visible when the click event was triggered so these options were filtered out and therefore did not get 'clicked'/'deselected'.
I amended my version of the plugin and now my 'reset' button works as expected. The new line is:

`this.$lis.not('.divider').not('.disabled').filter('.selected').find('a').click();`

Answer (score 17):

I got solution from following code.Try it

```
$("#listID").val('').trigger('change');
```

And also you can try this

```
$("#listID").val('').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's a little late, but maybe it'll help someone someday. For me the solution was this:

```
$("#listID").val([]).selectpicker('refresh');
```

I had the multiselect option and with this you replace your chosen items for an empty array, otherwise you'll choose the option where the value is empty val('').