# Bootstrap selectpicker not resetting to default when asked

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-select

I am asking `selectpicker()` to reset the select box to default or "no" value --  I have tried to use

```
$("#select_state").val('').selectpicker("refresh");
```

OR

```
$("#select_state").val('default').selectpicker("refresh");
```

Per [This Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27204404/bootstrap-selectpicker-will-not-reset-using-built-in-functions) and [This Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41883537/how-to-reset-value-of-bootstrap-select-after-button-click)

In addition, I found in the plugin a function called `deselectAll()` -- So I tried

```
$("#select_state").selectpicker("deselectAll");
```

To no avail.  Can someone direct me to the correct way to reset, or refresh the `selectpicker` -- As I think the plugin has been updated since the past questions I have been reading ...

My select looks like this --

```
<select id="select_state" title="State" data-live-search="true" data-style="btn-info" data-width="125px">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    ...
</select>
<script>
    $('#select_state').selectpicker();
</script>
```

**NOTE** There are no errors on the console log -- Adn the reset function fires just fine, and is resetting all my other fields to nothing IE

```
$('#email').val('');
$('#phone').val('');
$('#firstname').val('');
$('#lastname').val('');
$('#address').val('');
$('#city').val('');
$("#select_state").val('default').selectpicker("refresh");
$('#zip').val('');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing -- I set the `selectedIndex` to 0.  Then I refreshed it .. This is working for me.

```
var myselect = $("select#select_state");
myselect[0].selectedIndex = 0;
myselect.selectpicker("refresh");
```